# Joining relations in laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a product who has a feature, a feature have many values, so i associate the features to the product and the values to the product

so i search

```
Product::with('features', 'features.featureValue.product')->get();
```

how can i to make something like

```
Product::with('features', 'features.featureValue')
->where('features.featureValue.product.id','=', 'id')->get();
```

is that even possible, i mean how can i query an upper relation with an innner attribute?

Comment: Use with() in combination with whereHas(). http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

Comment: The "with" and "wherehas" is not the solution to my problem because the id is not a field that is inserted by the user but a property of Product, is like a join between relations of Product may be another case, in this case a join of a inner value with an outer